# Prevent collection modified exception in a foreach loop in c#

Tags: c#, dictionary, collections, foreach

I'm iterating over a dictionary `Dictionary<double, int> diametersAndQuantities` and the dictionary is modified. Obviously I'm getting an exception that the collection has been modified. How can I prevent this from happening?

```
foreach (var diametersAndQuantity in diametersAndQuantities)
{
    // some operations here

    // update
    diametersAndQuantities[db] = n;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a temporary list of the `KeyValuePair`s to iterate over and still update the dictionary.

```
foreach (var diametersAndQuantity in diametersAndQuantities.ToList())
{
    // some operations here

    // update
    diametersAndQuantities[diametersAndQuantity.Key] = n;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use the ToList() to get the enumeration to be evaluated
similar to accepted answer - maybe a little faster
should use less memory

```
Dictionary<int, int> dic = new Dictionary<int, int>() { { 1, 2 }, { 2, 3 }, { 3, 2 } };
foreach (int value  in dic.Values)
    Debug.WriteLine(value);
foreach (int key in dic.Keys.ToList())
    dic[key] = 12;
foreach (int value in dic.Values)
    Debug.WriteLine(value);
Debug.WriteLine("done");
```

Comment: @juharr `Value` (and also `Key`) is read only, so it's not going to *compile*.